# Selecting Key Value from json_decode in php

Tags: php, json

I have json objected

```
    stdClass Object ( [result] => stdClass Object ( 
[0] => 0110 
[1] => F02004010A8180040000000040000000 
[2] => 1234567890123456 
[3] => 182000 
[4] => 000002500000 
[11] => 398621 
[22] => 018 
[32] => 005 
[37] => 000317155213 
[39] => 00 
[41] => 00000011 
[48] => 1030 000000025000 0913144350153686 
[49] => 360 
[62] => 325191 
[98] => 013121212121 ) [errors] => Array ( ) )
```

my question, how to fetch value in object [39] with value 00?
Regards,

Comment: Give us the actual Json instead. That is unreadable for us. And to write a good question you should format it well and include what you have tried

Comment: `$obj->result->39`

Comment: I edited the question to readable json format. thx

Comment: Hai B.Desai, it gave error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '39' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: $obj->result->{39}

Comment: Solved using Mahesh way. $obj->result->{39}. Thanks Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible soltions. First, use the second param of `json_decode` to decode the array into an assoziative one.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['result'][39];
```

The other solution would be to use the `{}` notation.

```
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->result->{39};
```

Using `{}` is neccessary, because it's forbidden in php (and almost every other language) to use numbers as first chars of identifiers.